# {JS} Returning Promise { < Pending > }

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm using discord.js. I have an eval command (code:

```js
 if (cmd === `${prefix}eval`) {
        if (message.author.id !== "627835075064627221") return;
        function clean(text) {
            if (typeof (text) === "string")
                return text.replace(/`/g, "`" + String.fromCharCode(8203)).replace(/@/g, "@" + String.fromCharCode(8203));
            else
                return text;
        }
        try {
            const code = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
            let evaled = eval(code);

            if (typeof evaled !== "string")
                evaled = require("util").inspect(evaled)


            let evalCode = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("**EVAL**")
                .setDescription(clean(evaled), { code: "xl" })
                .setColor("RANDOM")
                .setFooter("Spood's Lounge | Eval")



            message.channel.send({ embed: evalCode });
        } catch (err) {
            message.channel.send(`\`ERROR\` \`\`\`xl\n${clean(err)}\n\`\`\``);
        }
    }
```

and when I do something to eval `message.reply("hello world!")` it just returns  `Promise { < Pending > }`. When I try to do other things like eval `console.log("hello world!")` it returns undefined.

How can I fix it so it returns the actual value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Nope. It doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the promise to resolve using `await`

```js
let evaled = await eval(code);
```